# DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. And not showing any missing DLL file name

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I'm on windows 10, I'm getting this error but cant see any helpful clue to fix this. I'm trying to install tensorflow and my python version is 3.6. Can any one help me to fix this.

```
     (venv) D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP Project\FYPProject>python
     Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
     Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
     >>> import tensorflow as tf
     2020-02-03 08:25:40.694788: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened 
     dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP 
     Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
     from tensorflow_core import *
     File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP 
     Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP 
     Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
     module = self._load()
     File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP 
     Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
    File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP 
    Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
    File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
    File "D:\Work\IIT\Fourth Year\Submission\FYP\FYP 
    Project\FYPProject\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
    >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found this. First uninstall the existing tensorflow using

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

And install again using this,

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```

if the 'tf_utils' error come you can try this,

```
pip install keras==2.1.5
```